# Different result in the same query from CLI than from lambda console

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get data from ENTSOE from this repository:
[Entsoe py](https://github.com/EnergieID/entsoe-py)

I'm using the EntsoePandasClient client.
Here goes my problem: using the same piece of code, same input, same everything, i get different outputs executing this query from my environment by CLI than from lambda console:

`ts = client.query_generation_per_plant('FR', start=start,end=end)`

If I execute it from my environment i get a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame with 24 rows x 140 columns with exactly what I expect to get. Something like this:

```
                              IGLE 6  AMFARD14  AMFARD15  ARRIGHI 1  ARRIGHI 2  ...  VAIRES 1  VAIRES 2  VAIRES 3  VILLARODIN 1  VILLARODIN 2
2020-11-17 00:00:00+01:00      0.0      70.0      71.0        0.0        0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0           0.0           0.0
2020-11-17 01:00:00+01:00      0.0      71.0      71.0        0.0        0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0           0.0          72.0
```

However, the same code in a lambda function executed from lambda console returns ts.columns as a MultiIndex, resulting in a 24 rows x 166 columns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. It's like it is getting two more rows of columns:

```
                                           AIGLE 6  ...          VILLARODIN 2
                                           Hydro Water Reservoir  ... Hydro Water Reservoir
                                           Actual Aggregated  ...     Actual Aggregated
2020-11-17 00:00:00+01:00                   0.0  ...                   0.0
```

Firstly i thought it was a problem with libraries version, but they are the same version in my environment and in my requirements.txt which I install during the deployment of the lambda.

I know this is a very concrete problem, but if anyone can help I'd be really greatful.

Comment: Can you provide any simple, minimal reproducible example code for the issue?

Comment: @Marcin I added an example code at the end of the question

Comment: I'm getting `[24 rows x 157 columns]`. Not sure if this is better or worse then what you have.

Comment: I get [24 rows x 140 columns], i guess that if you execute ts.columns you get a multiindex, is that right? In that case, do you mind doing a pip freeze to see the versions of 'requests', 'pytz', 'beautifulsoup4' and 'pandas' libraries?

Comment: Yes its `MultiIndex`. I'm running this on lambda, so I can't do pip freeze. But I installed this [requirements.txt](https://github.com/EnergieID/entsoe-py/blob/master/requirements.txt) from Entsoe py

Comment: Okay, thank you. I opened an issue a few days ago because in the setup.py it installs libraries in an array called install_requires, not libraries from requirements.txt. But that's out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

I created my own lambda layer with `entsoe-py` and dependencies listed in [requirements.txt](https://github.com/EnergieID/entsoe-py/blob/master/requirements.txt).

Using the sample code provided the output is (partial printout):

```
                                        AIGLE 6  ...          VILLARODIN 2
                          Hydro Water Reservoir  ... Hydro Water Reservoir
                              Actual Aggregated  ...     Actual Aggregated
2020-11-23 00:00:00+01:00                   0.0  ...                  93.0
            109.0
...
...
...
2020-11-23 23:00:00+01:00                  35.0  ...                  87.0

[24 rows x 157 columns]



MultiIndex([(         'AIGLE 6', 'Hydro Water Reservoir', ...),          
          ...
          ...
            (    'VILLARODIN 2', 'Hydro Water Reservoir', ...)],
           length=157)
```